# JSON Data Not Showing With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am learning about JSON and I am having trouble displaying data from an endpoint. This first segment of code works just fine for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>

    <script>
    $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com', function(data) {
        
        var text = `Date: ${data.date}<br>
                    Time: ${data.time}<br>
                    Unix time: ${data.milliseconds_since_epoch}`
                    
        
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Changing the script to this endpoint does not display any data. How can I show this data?

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/games/halo-the-master-chief-collection/xbox-one/game-history?gamertags=ice%20cold%20bepsi&gameVariant=all&view=DataOnly', function(data) {
        var text = `Gamertag: ${data[0].Gamertag}`
                    
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: check whether `data[0]` exist or not. are you able to `console.log(data)`

Comment: "...does not display any data" - what does it display?

Comment: If I paste that 2nd url directly in my browser, it asks me to authenticate. Which means, you need to provide access token/authorization code with your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into it, it seems like you need to authenticate to get this data. If no json is returned, then the callback will not run.  That's why if you put anything in the callback, even `console.log("HERE")`, it will not reach it.

If you want to authenticate, you will need to do an ajax request.  `$.getJSON` is just a wrapper around `$.ajax` anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked this because I was already authenticated when visiting the link in my browser.